# Why is curs_refresh() so slow?

Tags: c, ncurses

I tried using *ncurses* to make a simple file viewer that allows the user to scroll through a file and that shows a status bar at the bottom.

The problem is that `refresh()` (called through `getch()`) is too slow. Unlike in Vim, the scrolling is not smooth and it hangs and stutters occasionally.

This is the full source code, compiled using `gcc main.c -lncurses`:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MIN(a, b) ({ \
    __auto_type _a = (a); \
    __auto_type _b = (b); \
    _a < _b ? _a : _b; \
})

struct line {
    int indent;
    chtype *text;
    size_t ntext;
};

struct buffer {
    struct line *lines;
    size_t nlines;
    size_t nbytes;
};

struct buffer buf;

WINDOW *view_win;
int view_width, view_height;
size_t v_scroll;

void buf_draw_lines(int y, size_t from, size_t to);

void update_size(void)
{
    view_width = COLS;
    view_height = MIN((size_t) (LINES - 1), buf.nlines);
    if (view_win != NULL)
        delwin(view_win);
    view_win = newwin(view_height, view_width, 0, 0);
    scrollok(view_win, true);
    buf_draw_lines(0, 0, buf.nlines - 1);
    /* Draw full status bar */
    mvprintw(LINES - 1, 0,
        "%4zu-%4zu/%4zu (%3d%%) %zub (view=%dx%d) (term=%dx%d)",
        v_scroll + 1, v_scroll + view_height,
        buf.nlines,
        buf.nlines == (size_t) view_height ? 100 :
            (int) (100 *
                v_scroll / (buf.nlines - view_height)),
        buf.nbytes,
        view_width, view_height,
        COLS, LINES);
    hline(' ', COLS - getcurx(stdscr));
}

int line_append(struct line *line, char ch)
{
    chtype *newtext;

    if (line->ntext == 0 && isblank(ch)) {
        line->indent += ch == ' ' ? 1 : 8;
        return 0;
    }
    newtext = realloc(line->text, sizeof(*line->text) * (line->ntext + 1));
    if (newtext == NULL)
        return -1;
    line->text = newtext;
    line->text[line->ntext++] = ch;
    return 0;
}

struct line *buf_newline(void)
{
    struct line *newlines;

    newlines = realloc(buf.lines, sizeof(*buf.lines) * (buf.nlines + 1));
    if (newlines == NULL)
        return NULL;
    buf.lines = newlines;
    newlines += buf.nlines;
    memset(newlines, 0, sizeof(*newlines));
    buf.nlines++;
    return newlines;
}

int buf_read_file(const char *file)
{
    int fd;
    char b[1024];
    struct line *line;
    ssize_t r;

    if ((fd = open(file, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        return -1;

    buf.nlines = 0;
    buf.nbytes = 0;
    if ((line = buf_newline()) == NULL) {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
    while ((r = read(fd, b, sizeof(b))) > 0)
        for(const char *p = b; r; r--, p++) {
            if (*p == '\n' && ((line = buf_newline()) == NULL))
                goto sudden_out_of_mem;
            if (*p != '\n' && line_append(line, *p) < 0)
                goto sudden_out_of_mem;
            buf.nbytes++;
        }

/* fall through */
sudden_out_of_mem:

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

void buf_draw_lines(int y, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    if (to >= buf.nlines)
        to = buf.nlines - 1;
    if ((size_t) (view_height - y) <= to - from)
        to = view_height - y + from - 1;
    for (; from <= to; from++, y++) {
        const struct line *const line = buf.lines + from;
        mvwaddchnstr(view_win, y, line->indent,
            line->text, line->ntext);
    }
}

void handle_char(int c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case KEY_RESIZE:
        update_size();
        break;
    case 'j':
    case KEY_DOWN:
        if (v_scroll == buf.nlines - view_height)
            break;
        v_scroll++;
        wscrl(view_win, 1);
        buf_draw_lines(view_height - 1,
            v_scroll + view_height - 1,
            v_scroll + view_height - 1);
        break;
    case KEY_UP:
    case 'k':
        if (v_scroll == 0)
            break;
        v_scroll--;
        wscrl(view_win, -1);
        buf_draw_lines(0, v_scroll, v_scroll);
        break;
    case KEY_HOME:
    case 'g':
        v_scroll = 0;
        werase(view_win);
        buf_draw_lines(0, 0, buf.nlines - 1);
        break;
    case KEY_END:
    case 'G':
        v_scroll = buf.nlines - view_height;
        werase(view_win);
        buf_draw_lines(0, buf.nlines - view_height, buf.nlines - 1);
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <file name>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    initscr();
    noecho();
    raw();
    curs_set(0);
    start_color();
    keypad(stdscr, true);
    scrollok(stdscr, true);
    idlok(stdscr, true);

    if (buf_read_file(argv[1]) < 0) {
        endwin();
        fprintf(stderr, "error reading file '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    refresh();
    attr_set(A_REVERSE, 0, NULL);
    update_size();

    /* Main loop */
    while (1) {
        mvprintw(LINES - 1, 0, "%4zu-%4zu",
            v_scroll + 1, v_scroll + view_height);
        wrefresh(view_win);
        const int c = getch();
        if (c == 0x03 || c == 'q')
            break;
        handle_char(c);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < buf.nlines; i++)
        free(buf.lines[i].text);
    free(buf.lines);

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if there is an issue at my code or if ncurses is just slow. Removing `start_color()` considerably increased the performance and so did making the terminal size smaller.

I tried holding down the `j` key and using `xset r rate 200 50` and the program couldn't keep up with the scrolling.

Do I have to use lower level curses routines now to try and somehow optimize it or am I missing something?

---

**Edit:**
Now I've tried to make a new program using termios and ansi escape codes and the difference was not noticeable from Vim. But re-implementing the wheel and making curses 2.0 is what I had planned.

#### I Investigated further

I used Alacritty to compare Vim and my program like so:
`GALLIUM_HUD=fps alacritty -e vim main.c`
`GALLIUM_HUD=fps alacritty -e ./a.out main.c`

And these - while holding down `J` - were the results (FPS):

```py
+--------+-----+------------+
| Size   | Vim | My program |
+--------+-----+------------+
| 79x48  | 51  |   50       |
| 159x48 | 51  |   39       |
+--------+-----+------------+

Monitor: 1280x800 60hz
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo P8600 (2) @ 2.401GHz
GPU: Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset
```

Comment: @erik258 `refresh()` is called by `getch()`, see: https://invisible-island.net/ncurses//man/curs_getch.3x.html for further information.

Comment: btw, how do you profile refresh of getch()? (btw, measuring "move(y, line->indent); addchnstr(line->text, line->ntext);" gives ~2-3usec on average for those calls in my env)

Comment: replacing 'getch()' with 'read(0, &c, 1) + refresh()' gives me ~100-150usec on average refresh() call, it's still not noticeably at scrolling

Comment: @yvs2014 I just replaced `getch()` with `refresh()` and made `c` a random key, either `j` or `k` and let it run for 30 seconds and then `gprof`. I made a little edit on my post.

Comment: running it randomly I cannot see movement at all (maybe because more-less equal j/k occurence). What is execution time of an average refresh() call in your case?

Comment: The cases in `handle_char` either repaint the screen, or scroll the screen.  In scrolling, it is not using a window (so the status line is always repainted).  Either way, if the screen is large, that's potentially a lot of work.

Comment: I don't see any difference between this program and vim in terms of scrolling speed. I timed it scrolling its own source code from top to bottom, and timed vim scrolling the same file; both took the same time.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Seems like painting the status line is indeed taking up a lot of time. Omitting the status bar code yields much higher performance. I'm not sure why the performance gap is so large.

Comment: Scrolling the whole screen and repainting the status line makes it hard for ncurses to see that you intended scrolling part of the screen.  Making a window for the scrolling part, and scrolling just that, e.g., with [wscrl](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_scroll.3x.html) is likely to improve things.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I tried making it a window but there was no noticeable difference (see updated code: `update_size()` and main loop). I also tried optimizing the status bar.

Comment: @yvs2014 I tried adding benchmark code. Weirdly enough, a full program had more refreshes per second than the full program. Scrolling didn't make a big difference for refreshes per time.

Comment: @cutecoder Can you notice unsmooth scrolling with ~10k refreshes per second? (10k/sec gives only 100usec on refresh)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't see your program going slow... I've been testing it at a speed of 1200 baud, and the refresh is working ok.

Probably you have misunderstood something about the design of the curses library.  It is designed to ooptimize the amount of output sent to the terminal, as in the old times of `vi` (not vim) tty lines were connected to low baudrates and so, the time transmitting each character was very important.

I mention vi (instead of vim) because vim is not a good example of good curses behaviour, as it draws and redraws many parts of the screen repeatedly (probably giving more priority to the amount of computation, against the possibility or redrawing some parts of the screen several times)  If you compare the redrawing of the screen at low rates, with vi (or the new nvi) program, at low baudrates, you will see a lot of differences.

I see your program doing redrawing the correct way (as it is done by nvi) which minimizes the number of characters drawn.  If you run on a true serial line at 1200 baud or less, you'll see the actual differences and you will see vim falling on its knees because of the amount of redrawings it does.  To test that I use a small program y wrote to run a normal xterm terminal at the speed fixed on the tty line (by means of the `stty` command) and I publish it in [Github](https://github.com/mojadita/slowtty.git).  Try it and set the line to 1200 baud and you will see both programs running and yours will be the winner. :)

Your program is a bit obscure, a bit unreadable, but you have done a good job on it.  It seems to work fine.

---

**Note:**  I have observed (on redimensioning the terminal window, because it enqueues a lot of resize operations while you drag the pointer) that you queue all the refreshes and execute them all in sequence.  You should check if there's still input to be processed and process it all (curses processes it in its ram based screen)  and avoid calling refresh for each tiny modification.  You will save a lot of updates if you can process all input in batches, and then call refresh.  This is done in vi (nvi) but not in vim, wich will have the same behaviour you state.  The purpose of refresh is precisely to allow you to unsynchronize screen updates with the amount of operations that must be done on screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The *note* is interesting; are you suggesting I should read multiple characters using [getchar()](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses//man/curs_getch.3x.html) and [nodelay()](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html)?

Good that you bring in baud rate. Previously, I've only tried the program in Alacritty. Now I tried using XTerm and my program ran smoothly whereas Vim stuttered a little.

Comment: The best thing to do is to read as many characters as available in your input channel.  The idea is to process those chars all together and then do a `refresh()` before the next read is made.  This is not possible with the window dimensions change, as it is handled normally with a signal coming in.  But you can ignore the signal and check the window size after a read (so you will get the window change only after a full read)  Just compare the actual size with the one you have cached inside and proceed.

Comment: @cutecoder "Previously, I've only tried the program in Alacritty. Now I tried using XTerm and my program ran smoothly" So, that slowness you've seen is only connected with input (or output) latencies of one specific terminal app (alacritty here)?

Comment: No, what I have observed is what happens when you resize the window, and this is because while you are dragging the pointer, a lot of window changes are sent, each of which trigger a total window update ---with probably a full refresh() of the screen.  If you run it with `slowtty` tool i post in the reference link, you can set baudrate to 1200 baud, and watch the refreshes happening at 1200 speed (like in an old serial rs232c terminal)  this is what I did to see what was happening.  Better if you have a true serial terminal, but it's hard to have one today :)

Comment: @LuisColorado just thought something like https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/6844 can be related to lags observed in the original question, not vi/vim/ncurses peculiarities themselves